# nodejs, async in reduce, await doesn't wait for promise resolve

Tags: node.js, async-await

I don' get why all promises are resolved in same time.
I read that `await` doesn't work as expected in `forEach` loop, but it doesn't work with `map` either

```
const promise = async (ms, name) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`resolving ${name}`)
            resolve(name)
        }, ms)
    });
}

async function main() {
    ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].reduce(async (accum, curr) => {
        const res = await promise(1000, curr)
        return res
    }, Promise.resolve(''))
}

main()
```

But await works fine in this scenario:

```
async function main2() {
    const ms = 1000
    await promise(ms, "foo")
    await promise(ms, "bar")
    await promise(ms, "baz")
}

main2()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Each iteration of the `reduce` callback will be initialized *synchronously*. You need to wait for the accumulator from the last iteration (which is luckily a `Promise` already) to resolve before running the body of the `reduce` callback:

```js
const promise = async (ms, name) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log(`resolving ${name}`)
            resolve(name)
        }, ms)
    });
}

async function main() {
    ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'].reduce(async (accum, curr) => {
        // don't progress further until the last iteration has finished:
        await accum;
        const res = await promise(1000, curr)
        return res
    }, Promise.resolve(''))
}

main()
```

Comment: Cool, is it possibe to achive the same result but with `map` instead of `reduce`?

Comment: It's possible, but a lot uglier; you'd have to `await` an outer variable that gets continuously reassigned in place of `await`ing the accumulator. The resulting array would be an array of Promises.

Comment: ok, why one `await` is not enough? I thought `await promise(1000, curr)` will force node not to continue. Why do i need to `await` for accum? initial value of accum is already resolved before first cycle, isn't it?

Comment: Like I said, each iteration of the `reduce` callback will be initialized synchronously; `reduce` doesn't care if the prior value of the accumulator is a `Promise`, it won't wait for it unless you explicitly tell it to. It's different from a `for` loop, because each `await` is in a separate function